# Rewrite Nginx with $1 argument

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite an url to another one, but i can't use the $1 correctly:

```
location ~ ^/announce {
    rewrite ^(.*)$1 http://exemple.com/$1/announce.php?ip=$remote_addr&$args;
}
```

In fact `http://jack.exemple.com:2052/anything/announce` should become `https://exemple.com/anything/announce.php?ip=$remote_addr&`

That's work without the `$1`, but not with args beetwin `http://jack.exemple.com:2052/` and `/announce`

I think it's something pretty simple, but not so common, and I can't find the good syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is as simple as removing the "1" from the $ in your reg-ex "^(.*)$1" as per below ...

```
location ~ ^/announce {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://exemple.com/$1/announce.php?ip=$remote_addr&$args;
}
```